# How many messages a second can I fetch with discord.js to prevent API abuse?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a (personal) bot to download all messages that have been sent inside a channel, the messages are quite a lot and I know the limit of messages you can fetch is 100 per command, doing more than this results in API abuse and could get you banned.
Now let's take for example a command that returns the last 100 messages sent, an user can do that indefinite amount of times and it's not API abuse, so how many times a second can I do it for it to not be abuse?

I asked in the discord.js server but haven't gotten an answer after 3 tries and I honestly don't want to risk getting banned.

Comment: You get rate limited if you're doing things too quick, if you want to know how long different types of rate limits are, I suggest you make use of the `rateLimit` event: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-rateLimit

Comment: AFAIK though, storing messages is against Discord's ToS

Comment: Yup seems like it's against ToS but honestly, I just need to backup messages sent in a private channel where me and a friend sent messages, I'll email discord to ask what other ways I could do this

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to get banned, you might not want to try doing this, but I've already seen users make use of [webhooks](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Webhook) in order to restore some server's messages.

From personal experience, I know your bot gets rate limited for a few seconds if you send 5 messages in less than 1-2 seconds, so I would suggest you to send at most 1 message each 1-2 seconds and see whether you get rate limited or not.

You might also need to make sure that what you will be doing isn't against [Discord's ToS](https://discord.com/developers/docs/legal) if you really don't want to risk getting banned.

Comment: It looks like it's against ToS to store user data, I'll ask discord with how I should do this. The way I know would be that both me and the other person where I want to get the messages of request "all data" and then share the file of the specific channel

Comment: I accidentally fetched 50k messages instead of the limit I wanted to (20 messages) so let's see if I get banned lol

Comment: @Specy Well, fingers crossed ;p Could you let us know if you fo get banned, even if I don't think you will be

Comment: I hope i won't have to tell you that lol. But I asked in the discord.js server and a moderator told me "yes, I'm at discord hq rn and we are banning you in this moment" so I guess it's fine lol

Comment: @Specy I guess you're fine then ;) Be careful next time